# Ethereum contract disappears

Tags: ethereum, solidity

The following issue I am coming across with relation to the Ethereum geth and the mist wallet is that I have created a contract and it will disappear.
**Note, I am utilizing the private network to create the contracts within Ubuntu Linux.**

In addition to this issue, I am unable to decipher the input data using the command web3.toAscii(hash).

The issue with the web3.toAscii problem could be due to me executing the contract creation within the mist wallet, but I am not sure.

Are there any suggestions on how to fix such issue of a disappearing contract and not being able to get any block data as well?

Here is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Forensics{

string public info;
string public ForensicsSpecName;
string public AdditionalInfo;
string public timedate;

    function getForensName(string name){
        ForensicsSpecName = name;
    }

    function getInfo(string Info){
        info = Info;
    }

    function getAdditionalInfo(string ainfo){
        AdditionalInfo = ainfo;
    }

    function getdatetime(string information){
        timedate = information;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be better on [ethereum.se]?

Comment: I would consider using the private-based Ethereum, but I wanted the students to be able to follow along with my example and play around with the contract themselves.